# PHPUnit mock method from another class

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

With PHPUnit 6.5.14, I am trying to test a method. To do this, one of its dependencies needs to be mocked; however I can't get it working. Here is a stripped down version:

```php
class Order {
  public function create() {
    $CCP = new CreditCardProcessor();
    $success = $CCP->chargeCreditCard();
    return $success;
  }
}


class CreditCardProcessor {
  public function chargeCreditCard() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```php
class OrderTest extends TestCase {
  public function testCreate() {
    $mockCCP = $this->getMockBuilder(CreditCardProcessor::class)
      ->setMethods(['chargeCreditCard'])
      ->getMock();

    $mockCCP
      ->method('chargeCreditCard')
      ->willReturn(true);

    $O = new Order();
    $success = $O->create();

    $this->assertTrue($success, 'Was not able to create order.');
  }
}
```

I've read the docs and gone over some examples but can't figure it out. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After finding more examples, I believe the solution is to pass in the dependency to `create` as an argument:

```php
class Order {
  public function create($CCP) {
    $success = $CCP->chargeCreditCard();
    return $success;
  }
}
```

Then I can do the same in my test:

```php
class OrderTest extends TestCase {
  public function testCreate() {
    $mockCCP = $this->getMockBuilder(CreditCardProcessor::class)
      ->setMethods(['chargeCreditCard'])
      ->getMock();

    $mockCCP
      ->method('chargeCreditCard')
      ->willReturn(true);

    $O = new Order();
    $success = $O->create($mockCCP);

    $this->assertTrue($success, 'Was not able to create order.');
  }
}
```

I haven't tried yet, but that should do it.

I don't like the idea of changing code to satisfy tests, but it probably is also an indication I need to restructure my code.